# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined in Ionic3 project

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I tried to use the latest version of cordova-plugin-firebasex for my ionic3 app. I also did refer the ionic3 example for firebasex plugin. But after adding the code, I am getting the error as 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined'. Below is the code which I have used:

In my login.ts file:

```
if ( this.accessToken ) {
this.fireBaseService.getFirebaseXToken();
}
```

In my firebase-service.ts file===**====

```
export class FireBaseService {
protected token:any;
public firebasePlugin;

async getFirebaseXToken() {
let token;
this.firebasePlugin = (window).FirebasePlugin;
token = await this.firebasePlugin.getToken(token => {
console.log('Response from getToken===>>>>',token);
});
}
}
```

These are the specs for my ionic3 project:
"cordova": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-android": "8.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^8.1.1",
"cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": "3.0.0",
"cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "1.1.0",

"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
"typescript": "~2.6.2"
}

If there are any changes to be done in my code, am I missing something, any kind of help will be helpful. Thanks.